# Euclid's elements proposition 17. The sum of two angles in a triangle is less than 180 degres.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a very short question on this proposition :
http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI17.html

I understand the way the theorem was proved. Euclid proves that angles ABC and ACB is less than 180 degrees. At the end, he says the same method can be applied to prove for the other cases. I was able to do the same for the angle BAC and ACB. But how do I do it for CAB and ABC ? It doesn't seem the same method holds for this case, am I right ?

Comment: It will be difficult for anyone to answer this question unless you give some indication of why the third case (CAB and ABC) looks different to you from the other two cases.  Without such an indication, the only answer I could give is that it's exactly the same as the previous cases; only the names of the points have been permuted.

Comment: Oh, I understood my error. The reason why I thought it was different was because the proof relies on proposition 16 which states that the exterior angle is bigger than interior-opposite angles. (Not the adjacent one) So, I couldn't use the proposition 16 because ACB is adjcent to the exterior one. So, for the third case, I only extended the line from the other side (line BD) and applied proposition 16 this way (CAB and ABC). Unless I'm still doing an error ?